# Automatically add database entry after ftp upload

Tags: sql, file-upload, ftp

Sorry if this seems stupid but I wonder if it's possible to add a database entry after an ftp upload.

To be more clear, thanks to winSCP I have several folders sending everything I put in there automatically to my server. 
However, I would like to create a mysql entry for each uploaded files and once again, automatically. Is it possible to do that? How?

---

To gives the full details of what I need to do, you can read the following.
I have several folders with pictures and each folders are uploaded automatically. 
Each of those folders belong to one user and the goal is to give them an account and allow them to see and download those files through a web interface. Since one account = one folder, that's kinda easy. 
*And I think a simple .htaccess can simply secure things so one user can only see and download the file in his own repository, no?*

However if I want them to be able to see what's new (=something they didn't download or simply mark as read) I think I need a table to manage those files. 
Something like id | file (string) | read (bool).

If you think this way to proceed is bad, they I'm open to change how to do things, but to be clear uploading the file need to work this way. Not using any kind of formulary.

Thanks for reading that, sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem contains three steps:

1. Folders/Files been automatically uploaded to your server directory, as you say, this been efficiently handled by winSCP.
2. You need to update your database with all the files and folders present in your server directory.
3. You need to update whether or not it is been read/downloaded by the user.

Since your first step is in place, we don't need anything there. For second step, you should write a script and schedule that script to run at a fixed time interval using CRON (if using [LINUX or UNIX](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/), or [WINDOWS](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/setting-up-cron-for-drupal/configuring-cron-jobs-with-windows)). The script would be responsible to create a list of file(s) present in the directory, and simply insert the file(s) information that are not present in your database.

**EDIT:**
This edit is to describe how your script file should work. As I explained, the cron jobs would simply help you run your script file in fixed set of interval (which can be every minute, or every hour, or every day, and so on). Lets say your database table has following columns:

1. fileid (varchar[20])
2. filepath (varchar[20])
3. status (boolean)

Your script file should do following things:

1. Create a list of existing filepaths in your server directory
2. Run a select query, create a list of existing filepaths from database table.
3. Compare list1 with list2, and find the ones that doesn't exist in list2 (This would give you a list of filepath that needs to be inserted into table)
4. Just insert the list of file paths you got above, and set there status to be false (which means the file is not read/downloaded yet)

**NOTE**: Please keep in mind that I am not advising right now that how your database table should look like. It can be what you have proposed or can even differ depending on your will or requirements.

For the third step, simply keep the status of your file to be unread when creating entries in your table from the second step, and then when user click on the file link in your application whether to view or download it, send a POST request to your server updating the file status to be marked as read.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Well helping a bit. For the first and third step as you describe, I don't have any problem.
However, for the second, I'll see if this is possible to do that on my server. That's a web server (ovh) but in this case how should I proceed? List all the files everytime and create an add or update request for each file? 
Or maybe it should be possible to take the files posted the last hours or day and do that script on thoses files. 
Because if there's a problem of date on the server, it may cause problem of files not being added properly no?

Comment: I apologize for the late reply, was not available this weekend. But I just answered the way your script file would work. I believe you were looking for the same stuff. I don't see a case for which you should be worried about the date. Your script file would be simply dumping into table whatever is not present. Let me know if it helps you!